# Simple custom CAS server built with apache shiro

Tags: single-sign-on, java-ee-6, cas, shiro

I have been looking for a way to create a very simple authentication related CAS server with apache shiro. Why I have a very specific requirement on the server especially for signup where I actually try to map all the accounts with a master password . Reason being I still want existing users to still authenticate with the their old system where password in each system is hashed with different algorithm.

I thought I could do so with the shared session features of shiro using `ehcache` even `terracotta` clustering to keep the sessions.I got stuck in my thought on where to do the redirection from upon successful password challenge. All this are just assumptions because I can't really see the bigger picture.

I have seen a lot of people leveraging on `jasig-cas` but it doesn't seem to me after reading some of their documentation that I can have the freedom and the control I would have when implementing this very very simple CAS server on shiro. Besides I wanted to run mongodb as backend for the CAS server and I have't seen that in the list of `datasource` one can use.

If anybody has tried this before kindly share your discovery and point us to the right direction.
Thanks